# Stripe checkout subscriptions with quantity in Laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel Cashier and have a simple setup of a subscription with a tiered quantity ($x for the first unit, $y for subsequent units).

Creating the subscription with the quantity is easy in Cashier:

```
$user->subscription('main')->quantity(5)->create($token);
```

It looks like Stripe checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) doesn't support a quantity to match the subscription, so do I have to calculate the total to add into the `data-amount` field before making the call to checkout? It seems odd that checkout doesn't match the functionality of the subscription API.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
    data-amount="{{$plan->amount}}"
    data-name="People Like Us"
    data-email="{{Auth::user()->email}}"
    data-description="{{$plan->nickname}}"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() }}"
    data-currency="usd"
    data-label="@lang('auth.paybutton')">
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, you need to perform the calculation for the `data-amount` field yourself. Checkout is mainly optimised for straightforward flows to let you get up-and-running as fast as possible, and it pre-dates the API functionality for having multiple plans in a subscription by a bit

Comment: Ok, ta, just wanted to confirm before I went down that path.